# Apply a custom directive to a form

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-forms

I am trying to add a custom directive that will catch the `submit` event and execute some operations.

This is the directive that I am trying to create:

```
import { Directive, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[validate-form]',
  host: {
    '(ngSubmit)': 'onSubmit($event)'
  }
})
export class FormValidationDirective implements OnInit  {

  constructor(
    public form: FormGroup
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onSubmit($event) {
    console.warn("submit");
  }
}
```

Since I am using it from a shared module, this is how I declared it:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FormValidationDirective,
    //...
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    //...
  ],
  exports: [
    FormValidationDirective,
    //...
  ]
})
export class mySharedModule { }
```

And this is how I call it in the template:

```
<form validate-form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
```

but accessing the component's page ends with the error:

```
 StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FormValidationDirective -> FormGroup]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for FormGroup!
```

Comment: Have you added the directive correctly in the app.component.ts? Check that you have it listed in the providers section.

Comment: I am using it from a shared module, I edited the question to show how I declared it

Comment: FormGroup isn't an Injectable Service. Did you mean to make it an input property instead of instantiate it on the constructor?

Comment: That was right, adding an input to the directive saved the problem: `@Input('validate-form') form: FormGroup;`, and in the template `<form [validate-form]="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">`. You can add it as an answer, so I can accept it